# Is the given straightforward double integration solution wrong?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

A solution in my *Student solutions manual* proceeds:
$$\int_{-3}^3\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}(y+y^2\cos{x})\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int_{-3}^{3}\left[xy+y^2\sin{x}\right]_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2}dy$$.

I thought $k\frac{d}{dx}\cos{x}=-k\sin{x}$.  Could someone be so kind as to show me how to follow this?

Comment: $\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin x = \cos x$, so $\int \cos x = \sin x + C$

Comment: It's been a really long week.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \sin x={\large \color{red}-} \cos x+\mathcal C\quad \text{as}\quad \frac{d}{dx}\cos x={\large \color{red}-}\sin x\\
\int \cos x={\large \color{red}+} \sin x+\mathcal C\quad \text{as}\quad \frac{d}{dx}\sin x={\large \color{red}+}\cos x$$